# Error in "Quandl" while pulling data for commodity in R

Tags: r, finance, quandl, commodity

I am trying to pull data for commodity Soybean Meal, Central Illinois using code `WSJ/SOYB_MEAL` in the following R function . I am using package `Quandl`

```
 library(Quandl)
 mydata = Quandl("WSJ/SOYB_MEAL")
 head(mydata)
```

It's giving me following error

```
Error: {"quandl_error":{"code":"QECx02","message":"You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again."}}
```

I would appreciate any kind if help in this regard.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: From Quandl's search I could only find COM/SOYB_MEAL, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Quandl and Newyork167 is right. `WSJ/SOYB_MEAL` is actually a deleted source. Please do use `COM/SOYB_MEAL` instead: https://www.quandl.com/data/COM/SOYB_MEAL

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14640510)

Comment: @BinayaRegmi This is not a llink-only answer. If the link were removed, it would still be an answer to the question.